# Ejabberd Roster management with mobile client

Tags: android, chat, ejabberd, smack, rosters

While implementing a chat application. I had created a REST API to manage user contacts and this user management API updates Ejabberd rosters as needed.

What is the best practice while managing user contacts in chat application via Ejabberd? After going through docs, what I have understood roster is used for user's presence rather than contacts.

Is roster only for user's presence management? Mobile client should communicate with the Ejabberd to post users contacts or my current approach of doing it via an external API is fine?

Thanks in advance.